# Why does not Entity Framework allow migration of 2 contexts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

In my previous project I had two DbContexts:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

And I had no problem creating and migrating my database. Today I created a new project that has only two contexts too and I can not migrate the database and stackoverflow suggests to make separate migrations, store them in separate folders, etc. What did I do wrong that I can migrate two contexts with one simple command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would require two separate connections for that in web.config. Each for one respective dbcontext. Two dbContexts cannot share a connection.